# google play console problem image quality

Tags: google-play-console

I have a problem on the sheet of my application on the store (on phone), the icon and the other presentation images are ugly / pixelated but when I go to the CG = Hie from the console the images are perfect!

[image]

No problem on the application, it's really the sheet that bugs!

The images were made with photopea,dimmension ok,600dpi,rgb

Is there a special setting?

Thank you in advance and have a good day

[Play store captur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f3SW.jpg)

[Play store captur2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs1VH.jpg)

[Real](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvDYY.jpg)

[Real IC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irn2y.png)

see the problem top..